# IBusControl Publish does nothing while wrapped into another class

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm struggling with MassTransit and here is another tricky issue that I failed to solve yet.
When I call Publish method directly, everything works fine and the message is sent to RMQ. But when I wrap this method with my own and inject bus in a wrapper class' constructor, it doesn't work. Messages simply do not get to the bus.

```
using (var uow = new Wrapper(ctx, bus))
{
    var itemMsg = new ItemChangedMessage() { Value = item.Value };

    uow.Publish(itemMsg); //Does not work

    bus.Publish(itemMsg); //Works fine
}
```

Here is a wrapper class' method. Nothing special.

```
public void Publish(IMessage message)
{
    bus.Publish(message);
    ...
}
```

I have absolutely no ideas what kind of a problem could be here. Tried different combinations with async\await stuff but nothing helped yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your wrapper gets disposed before the call completes since you are not awaiting the publish. You *must* do `async`/`await` or you can use `TaskUtil.Await(() => bus.Publish(message));` inside the wrapper.

This should work:

```
using (var uow = new Wrapper(ctx, bus))
{
    var itemMsg = new ItemChangedMessage() { Value = item.Value };

    await uow.Publish(itemMsg);
}
```

...

```
public async Task Publish(object message)
{
    await bus.Publish(message);
    ...
}
```

But the main issue is indeed something else. As correctly pointed in another answer, you are using the typed overload `Publish<T>(T message)` but your `T` is `IMessage`, so MassTransit will publish it to the `IMessage` exchange and since you most probably subscribe to `ItemChangedMessage`, your consumer never get it.

You can easily see this when looking at debug logs:

> [15:51:06 DBG] Exchange: BusWrapper:IMessage (durable)
>
> [15:51:06 DBG] SEND rabbitmq://localhost/BusWrapper:IMessage 1b340000-da2d-1866-1043-08d4de648414 BusWrapper.IMessage

You have no need to mark your messages with any interface, it only create unnecessary exchanges and dependencies, would you want to share your message interfaces as a library. You can be just fine with `public async Task Publish(object message)` as per updated code in this answer.

Alternatively, you can use the `Publish(object message)` overload, which will find the types for you and publish properly. In such case, you will need to have this in your wrapper:

```
public async Task Publish(IMessage message)
{
    await bus.Publish((object) message);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Have tried TaskUtil.Await(() => _bus.Publish(message)); as well, but it didn't help.

Comment: OK, I know what it is

Comment: @AlexeyKoptyaev updated my answer. I got burned by this a couple of times.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Finally, it works. I have to say that it is very unobvious behavior. But I still do not understand why I'm using generic method since I call simple Publish, so it should be `Task Publish(object message)`

Comment: This is how C# matches the signature. Since typed overload suits directly without casting - it is chosen before the the `object` overload because the latter requires casting down in class hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that Publish is generic and there is a different overload used in your method. Change your method signature to:

```
public void Publish<T>(T message) where T : IMessage
```

Comment: There is no need to have an interface

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev possibly, I don't know what publish expects but I left it there to keep it consistent with OP code

Comment: @MistyK Nope, it is the same overload since ItemChangedMessage implements IMessage

Comment: @AlexeyKoptyaev Alexey answer may be correct, since it returns task then you should await it. Anyway the thing which I described can also cause the issues because what if generic parameter T is read internally in the publish method? Without wrapper it will be of type ItemChangedMessage and with wrapper it will be of type IMessage

Comment: @MistyK your answer is essentially correct, I upvoted it.

Comment: @AlexeyKoptyaev yes, it is the same overload but you are publishing `IMessage` and what @MistyK suggest is to use the message type itself, which indeed would resolve your issue.